# How to recover a deleted git branch that was deleted and recreated?

Tags: git

I made a set of mistakes while attempting to do some sort of 3-way merge

The set of commands I made were as follows

```
git branch --delete branch1
git checkout branch2
git switch -c branch1
git push --force
```

I wanted to do these commands to branch3 instead of branch1 and i'm not sure how to get it back.
when i try git reflog i just get "branch: Created from HEAD" and can't find the commits i lost

**NOTE**:
I was wise enough to have a hard copy backup of branch1 sitting around but I suppose the question still stands, how could I have gotten the reflog of the old branch1?

Comment: `branch1` used to be a regular branch : it was created at some point, then you somehow ran `git checkout branch1` and did stuff on that branch, correct ?

Comment: run `git reflog | grep "checkout: .* to <branch1>"` to see if it is still in your reflog

Comment: @LeGEC branch1 used to be a regular branch, was deleted then recreated, no commits were made to it aside from being created

Also, I think I have a hard copy of the repo containing branch1, updating question

Answer (score 0):

*if you have a hard copy of the repo :*

run :

```
# get that commit from other repo :
git fetch ../path/to/that/copy branch1

# put branch1 on it :
git switch -C branch1 FETCH_HEAD
```

*from `git reflog` :*

note that your local reflog (`git reflog HEAD`) will be updated only if you *switched to that branch* out at some point.
If you only created that branch using `git branch branch1 <xyz>`, and then deleted that branch, it won't leave a trace in `HEAD`, and `git` has the unfortunate feature of deleting the reflog of a branch when you delete it (e.g: `git reflog branch1` is lost :/ ).

If you did switch to that branch :
you can spot the moment when you switched to that branch :

```
git reflog | grep "checkout: .* to <branch1>"
```

the sha at the beginning will be the commit *when you created that branch*.

If you want to have a good guess at the latest commit on branch1, check the reflog *when you left that branch* :
search for the latest "checkout: from branch1 ..." reflog line, and read the line below that:

```
$ git reflog | grep -A1 "checkout: fom <branch1>"
eacf32b checkout: from branch1 to other_branch
eacf32a ...                           # <- probably the latest commit on branch1
```